# Submerge PayPal buttons int one

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax, paypal

[image]
I actually am new to rails and PayPal I am trying to run f.submit to DB as soon as the transaction is completed. But two buttons are visible. I'm not able to mix them can someone please help

```
<!-- Set up a container element for the button -->
<div id="paypal-button-container class="form-group" >

    <!-- Include the PayPal JavaScript SDK -->
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&currency=USD"></script>

    <script>
        // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
        paypal.Buttons({

            // Set up the transaction
            createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                return actions.order.create({
                    purchase_units: [{
                        amount: {
                            value: '0.01'
                        }
                    }]
                });
            },

            // Finalize the transaction
            onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                    // Show a success message to the buyer
                    alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
                });
            }



        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
       </script>
       <%= form.submit %>

</div>
```

**Controllers file for orders new**

```
def create
@order = Order.new(order_params)
@listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id])
@seller = @listing.user

@order.listing_id = @listing.id
@order.buyer_id = current_user.id
@order.seller_id = @seller.id


respond_to do |format|
  if @order.save
    format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @order }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
 end
```